# Original source for the "play tennis" dataset

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, references

A famous toy example in machine learning, especially with learning decision trees, is the well known "play tennis" dataset. Is there an official source for the dataset which could be quoted in scientific work?

Answer (score 1):

After some more research, this looks like the originating source to me (correct me, if I'm wrong):

```
@article{Quinlan:1986,
    Author = {J. Ross Quinlan},
    Journal = {Machine Learning},
    Pages = {81--106},
    Title = {Induction of {D}ecison {T}rees},
    Volume = {1},
    Year = {1986}}
```